# Is it ok to rely on lots of third party packages?

Tags: python, django

My organization uses django for our website so we have the opportunity to use pypi packages, but we don't seem to have used many in the past and developers have written there own solutions instead. I've always used lots of packages in my own project. Is there really any downside to using these packages?

Comment: Honestly, it's the only way you'll get anything significant done. Maintaining a well-written library is a lot of work, and that overhead will keep building up until it's taking the majority of your dev cycles. Not to mention that most libraries deal with edge-cases that you probably haven't accounted for (timezones is usually a good "nightmare" example although django has that built-in)

Comment: I'd add to that that its worth making sure that the packages you use are actively maintained/stable, otherwise using a library that has flaws and is not maintained could cause you as big if not bigger problems than writing your own solutions

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think this a lot based on your opinion. 
Personally I would say it's a good idea to use a lot of third party packages. It enables you to develop faster and why inventing the wheel all over again?

Advantages:

- faster development
- DRY, don't reinvent the wheel
- higher likelihood that the tools are time-tested and have bugs worked out (@erip)

Disadvantages:

- support of third party packages could be dropped.
- sometimes they don't fit your needs exactly
- if open source license changes, you're suddenly without support or liable to a legal battle (@Sayse)

Comment: For the disadvantages, if it's open source you can just continue the work and modify it to fit your needs. Still might be a lot of work but better then starting from nothing.

Comment: I would add to advantages that there's a higher likelihood that the tools are time-tested and have bugs worked out.

Comment: Don't forget that if a third party suddenly changes its open source license, you're suddenly without support or liable to a legal battle.

Comment: Good points! I added these to the answer